# Area Line Plot in Python using Report Lab

Tags: python, plot, line, reportlab

I am using Reportlab to create some graphs in my PDF reports. I was creating an Area Line Plot and got stuck at a point where I am not able to understand why am I not getting the output I would like to see.

Here is the code I had written for my output:

```
def standardLinePlot(data, width=200, height=200):

    d = Drawing(width, height)
    lp = AreaLinePlot()
    lp.data=data
    lp.width, lp.height = width, height
    lp.xValueAxis.valueMin = 0
    lp.xValueAxis.valueMax =36
    lp.xValueAxis.valueSteps = [0,6,12,18,24,30,36]

    lp.yValueAxis.valueMin = 0
    lp.yValueAxis.valueMax =100

    lp.strokeColor=colors.black
    lp.fillColor=colors.grey

    lp.reversePlotOrder = False

    lp.joinedLines=1

    d.add(lp)

    return d
```

The output I am getting is:

[image: Area Line Plot]

My intended output is that grey color should be in place of red color which is the area under the line plot. The other problem is how can I add the axis title to this chart. For example, I need “Months” to be my X axis and “% of NAV” to be my Y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define the color for the lines it seems you need to access... well, the lines :). So, `lp.lines[0].strokeColor = colors.grey` instead of `lp.strokeColor = colors.grey`, as that one goes for the plot background color!

The question about the labels is a bit more tricky, though... `ScatterPlot` includes functionality to set labels for X and Y axis, but that's not the case for `AreaLinePlot`. Of course, you could derive a class from `AreaLinePlot` copying that functionality, if you're going to use it often.

Comment: Thank you jCollado for revising the question.

Comment: Ricardo: Thank you for your response! Apart from the color of the lines, I am looking to change the plot background color(color which depicts the area under the line). What would you suggest me to change the color red to some other color. Once again Thank you guys for helping me out.

Comment: @GulshanM: the point is that setting properties directly on the `AreaLinePlot` will make global changes. The `lp.strokeColor = colors.black` is making a black rectangular border appear, closing the axes area, and `lp.fillColor = colors.grey` is making the plot use grey as a background color for the whole thing. To modify the colors for the lines *and the area under them*, you have to access each line using `lp.lines`, as point out in the answer. For the lines there's no `fillColor`: the `strokeColor` is used instead to floodfill if the `inFill` property is set for *that* line.

Comment: Ricardo: I tried removing the strokeColor from the code and it did remove the black border. But I am still not able to understand how I am getting the red color in the area under the lines when I am using a grey color instead. Did you get a chance to look at the image I posted (jcollado has revised my question and reposted it)IN my graph, I am getting the grey color in an area which is not part of the data line. If you have, Could you send me an example of such graphs? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You get red instead of grey *BECAUSE YOU'RE NOT SETTING THE LINE COLOR*. Please, read my explanations. There is something you need to understand: you're not getting grey color "in the area which is not part of the data line". You're setting grey as **BACKGROUND COLOR** for the whole plot. If there were no data to plot, you'd see grey all around, no red. Why red for the area under the line plotted? I guess red is the default color for lines. You need to change the `strokeColor` for the *plotted line* to change the color under the line, and you do that as I told you in the answer

Comment: Just one detail: I think we need to agree on terminology. We're not calling "background color" to the same thing: I call that to the color that you'd see if there were no data plotted! And as I've told you before, to change the color that fills the area under the plotted line, you need to change the `strokeColor` for *that line*, because the same color will be used. And you don't do that by setting `lp.strokeColor`, but `lp.lines[n].strokeColor`, where `n` identifies the line (you could have plotted more than one dataset)

Comment: Ricardo: Thank you for the explanation. I was able to change the code and get what I wanted. Once again thank you for your help and being patient with my queries. I am very new to Python so think will have a steep learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
lp = AreaLinePlot()
```

to

```
lp = LinePlot()
```

and try that

```
lp.lines[0].strokeColor = colors.red
lp.lines[0].inFill = True
```

but the fill color will be the same as the line color.

credit goes to @Ricardo Cárdenes